# JQuery Javascript for loop stops after first iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]
 I have two `<ul>` lists, and I want to move a selected element from one to another after checking if it already exists in the destination list, so I had to create a function that compares the text of the the selected `<li>` with the `<li>` elements n the destination `<ul>`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('html').on('click', 'li', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    });

//Déplacer vers la gauche
$('#btnLeft').click(function() {    

    var elementExiste = function(liste,selectionne){
        var exists=false;
        for(var x=0; x<liste.length; x++){
            if(liste.children().eq(x).text()===selectionne){ 
                exists=true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return exists;
    }

    var bool = true;
    for(var i=0; i< $('.selected').length; i++){        
        if(elementExiste($('.list1'),$('.selected').eq(i).text())){
            alert('Cet élément existe déjà');
            bool = bool && false;
        }
        else {
            bool = bool && true
        }
    }

    if(bool)
            $('.list1').append($('.list2 .selected').removeClass('selected'));
    });
}
```

The for loop works fine for the first iteration, but it just breaks after this

Comment: Looks like you're looping on the items that are in the *first* list rather than the items that are in the *second* list.  If only 1 item is selected, the loop will only iterate once.

Comment: Or I'm trying to comment too fast and just have no idea what's really going on.

Comment: yes, in the code I published, I am trying to move the element "2" (for example) from list2 to list1

Answer (score 0):

You pass ul to the function so liste.length = 1
You could  pass all li elements:

```
elementExiste($('.list1 li'),$('.selected').eq(i).text()))
```

or pick li elements inside:

```
liste.children().length
```

so it could iterate through all of them.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! the first suggestion worked for me, I changed the body of the function elementExiste to this :  `function(liste,selectionne){  
   var exists=false;  
   for(var x=0; x<liste.length; x++){  
    if(liste.eq(x).text()===selectionne)  { 
     exists=true;  
     break;  
    }  
   }  
   return exists;`